# ipython in web browser doesn't work

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed the anaconda python3 distribution on Windows 7.  The python command line works fine.  When I type `"ipython notebook"`, however, the server starts and the browser starts and points to the correct local URL `(http://localhost:8888/tree)`, but the resulting page looks awful in my browser.  It doesn't look anything like the documentation.  It says "Jupyter" at the top, but the elements are not aligned.  I've posted a screen-shot at:

[image]

Perhaps a `.css` file (or something) isn't being read correctly.  Eventually, I want to run a Julia profile, and I am sure this is a simple problem (I just can't figure it out).

Comment: Your image should be posted in your post. I realise you don't have the reputation to do that so I'd do it for you, except you have linked to a PDF. If you change it to a JPG or PNG file I'll add it to your post.

Comment: Done.  The .png is at: smithw.org/ipython-notebook-screen-shot.png